# MySQLdb execute() works with unicode but not with subclass of unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, mysql-python

I am building a library that extends unicode class with some other methods, I discovered that MySQLdb is failing when using my unicode class.

This works :

```
In [23]: c.execute("""SELECT * FROM django_site WHERE domain LIKE %s""",(u'éric',))
Out[23]: 0L
```

But this not :

```
In [24]: class UnicodeExtended(unicode):
    ...:     pass
    ...: 

In [25]: c.execute("""SELECT * FROM django_site WHERE domain LIKE %s""",(UnicodeExtended(u'éric'),))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-9145669d2b00> in <module>()
----> 1 c.execute("""SELECT * FROM django_site WHERE domain LIKE %s""",(UnicodeExtended(u'éric'),))

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.pyc in execute(self, query, args)
    205                 args = dict((key, db.literal(item)) for key, item in args.items())
    206             else:
--> 207                 args = tuple(map(db.literal, args))
    208             if not PY2 and isinstance(query, bytes):
    209                 query = query.decode(db.unicode_literal.charset)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.pyc in literal(self, o)
    302 
    303         """
--> 304         s = self.escape(o, self.encoders)
    305         # Python 3 doesn't support % operation for bytes object.
    306         # We should decode it before using %.

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.pyc in string_literal(obj, dummy)
    213             # Note: string_literal() is called for bytes object on Python 3.
    214             def string_literal(obj, dummy=None):
--> 215                 return db.string_literal(obj)
    216             return string_literal
    217 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is it possible to use a sublass of unicode into sql queries parameters in any way ?

May be there is something missing into my UnicodeExtended class...Any idea ?

Im am using Python 2.7 and MySQLdb 1.3.7

Answer (score 0):

I found that MySQLdb is testing the UnicodeType directly, it does not support unicode subclassing. As a default, MySQLdb will do a str() on unrecognized object type. so the trick was to add the __str_ method :

```
class UnicodeExtended(unicode):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.encode('utf-8')
```

This is working. This also avoid the "_last_executed" error with django when using UnicodeExtended objects.